# SQLAlchemy: Subclassed model db entry gets properties of other subclassed model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having an issue with SQLAlchemy in a Flask app where I have two models `Instructor` and `Student` that subclass the same model `User`. When I'm creating a `Student` object, it's listed in the database under `User` with properties that should be unique for `Instructor`. Here are my (simplified) classes:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    discriminator = db.Column("type", db.String(50))  # Student or Instructor
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": discriminator}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50)) 

class Instructor(User):
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "instructor"}
    reputation = db.Column(db.Integer, default=1)
    approved_for_teaching = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

class Student(User):
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "student"}
    lessons_taken = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
```

I'm creating a `Student` like this:

```
new_student = Student(name=user_name)
db.session.add(new_student)
db.session.commit()
```

But when inspecting the object in the database, the student gets attributes from the `Instructor` model, i.e. `reputation` (value is 1) and `approved_for_teaching` (value is False). Am I doing something wrong here, or is this expected behaviour? I could understand if the columns would have to be present, since they share the same table (`User`) in the db, but then I'd expect the values to be null or something. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected behaviour, since you're using [single table inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#single-table-inheritance):

> Single table inheritance represents all attributes of all subclasses within a single table. A particular subclass that has attributes unique to that class will persist them within columns in the table that are otherwise NULL if the row refers to a different kind of object.

Though the documentation mentions leaving the columns belonging to other classes NULL, the client side defaults you've given the columns kick in during inserts to `user` table, which underlies all the classes inheriting from `User`, even when they're not a part of the particular subclass' columns. A [context sensitive default function](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#context-sensitive-default-functions) could perhaps be used to avoid that, for example:

```
def polymorphic_default(discriminator, identity, value):
    def default(context):
        # This should be replaced with context.get_current_parameters() in 1.2 and above
        if context.current_parameters[discriminator.name] == identity:
            return value
    return default

...

class Instructor(User):
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "instructor"}
    reputation = db.Column(
        db.Integer, default=polymorphic_default(User.discriminator, 'instructor', 1))
    approved_for_teaching = db.Column(
        db.Boolean, default=polymorphic_default(User.discriminator, 'instructor', False))
```

but that seems like a lot of work to avoid a rather small issue.